# Input without waiting in Julia

Tags: julia

I have to make a game in Julia for college, but I don't know how to make some sort of listener like in java. I mean, a way to get user input without having to stop everything else in the game. Is there a way to do it? I have been searching through the documentation but haven't found anything.

Comment: See also [Reactive.jl](https://github.com/JuliaGizmos/Reactive.jl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use GTK for handling the keypress in a window. This example was taken from the [GTK.jl readme](https://github.com/JuliaGraphics/Gtk.jl#callbacks-and-signals)

```
using Gtk
using Gtk.ShortNames

function key_pressed_cb(widget, event)
    @show [widget, event]
end

win = @Window("Main window")
showall(win)
id = signal_connect(key_pressed_cb, win, "key_press_event")

if !isinteractive()
    c = Condition()
    signal_connect(win, :destroy) do widget
        notify(c)
    end
    wait(c)
end
```